# How to show the input at end of my function

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the end of my code within the main function I ask the user if they want to try again but this does not show when executing the program. Here is my code

```
def get_factor_count(num):
    list = []
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
            if num % i == 0:
                list.append(num)      
    print(num, "has", len(list), "factors")

def main():
    num = int(input('\nPlease enter a number: '))
    while num < 1:
        print('NUMBER MUST BE GREATER THAN 1! Please try again.')
        num = int(input('\nPlease enter a number: '))
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                print(num, "IS NOT A PRIME NUMBER")

            else:
                print(num, "IS A PRIME NUMBER")
            return get_factor_count(num)

    again = input('Try again? (Y/N): ')
    while again.upper() == 'Y':
        num = int(input('\nPlease enter a number: '))
        main()
        if again.upper() == 'N':
            print('Goodbye')

main()
```

Comment: `return get_factor_count(num)` ends the function before you ask to try again. It ends the function after the first iteration of the `for` loop.